# Creating automated Tableau packaged workbooks (for Tableau Reader) using Alteryx TDE output

Tags: tableau-api, alteryx

I am running an Alteryx workflow on a dedicated PC, 4X a day. The Alteryx workflow creates a TDE output file that is the data source for a dashboard I would like to save as a packaged workbook (openable in Tableau Reader) and distribute 4X a day.

I have a Tableau online account and tried publishing an extract of the TDE file created by Alteryx to Tableau online, setting up a refresh schedule for that extract using Tableau online sync, and then linking my workbook to this Tableau online data source.

While that solution has worked well in terms of having 4X a day updated Tableau workbooks online, when I try to download the TWBX file, it does not contain the data extract (as the Tableau workbook has a "live" connection to the published Tableau data extract online) and thus cannot be opened in Tableau reader.

My main goal is to be able to automate production of Tableau packaged worbooks (a macro that opens Tableau and hits save would do the job), and would appreciate any creative suggestions / ideas.

Comment: This is something I am also trying to do at the moment but haven't figured out!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be accomplished.  You would need to leverage on-premise Tableau Server.

FWIW...Although many companies use Reader (due to the cost of server), it was never intended to be used in a production environment. Data is not governed or secure.